# Get the message from assert in symfony template

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a question related to Assert form validation in symfony. So I have :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="client.firstName.notBlank")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 2,
 *      max = 50,
 *      minMessage = "client.firstName.invalid",
 *      maxMessage = "client.firstName.invalid"
 * )
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern     = "/^[0-9]+$/i",
 *     htmlPattern = "^[0-9]+$",
 *     message="client.firstName.regex"
 * )
 */
protected $firstName;
```

And in validators.yml :

```
client:
    firstName:
        notBlank: 'Not Blank'
        invalid: 'Invalid'
        regex: 'Regex'
```

In form I have :

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.firstName) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ 'client.firstName'|trans({}, 'validators') }}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to submit the form I get the message : `client.firstName`. I need a way to get message from assert. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need add one other file for each your assert messages:

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml
client.firstName.notBlank: Please enter your firt name.
......
```

I think this is not necessary:

```
<div class="invalid-feedback">
    {{ 'client.firstName'|trans({}, 'validators') }}
</div>
```